# How to mock method from mocked library instance

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, pytest

Folks,

I have following situation:

tested_library:

```
class foo(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.bar = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('bar')

def get_status(self):
    trace_out = self.bar.some_method_from_mocked_lib()
    trace = re.findall(r'([A-Z\d]+)\s*(on|off)', trace_out )
```

Where `BuiltIn` is a robotframework library which is not working without robot's environment and python is not able to import this library because of `BuiltIn` and I had to mock it (below). `trace` is still used later and method `get_status()` returns something else.

test:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
from mock import MagicMock
monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()

def import_lib(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('robot.libraries.BuiltIn.BuiltIn.get_library_instance', MagicMock())
    import tested_library as lib
    return lib.foo

def test_getting_status():
    test_object = import_lib(monkeypatch)
    test_object.get_status()
```

But returns me:

```
pattern = '([A-Z\\d]+)\\s*(on|off)', string = <MagicMock name='mock().some_method_from_mocked_lib()' id='140623304433104'>, flags = 0
```

And the question is how to mock this, how to return string not an mocked object with method?

Comment: `lib.foo.get_status.return_value = 'some text'`?

Comment: Or, if you want to test `test_status` itself (looks like this is the case), mock `bar.some_method_from_mocked_lib`: `lib.foo.bar.some_method_from_mocked_lib.return_value = 'some text'`.

Comment: I can't mock whole method `get_status` because of it returns something else and variable `trace` is still used later.

Comment: Then mock `bar.some_method_from_mocked_lib`, as in the comment above.